# Is there a way to give fetched items an initial value instead of null?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, typeerror

When I go to upload an image I get thrown this error because `item.id` is null initially: `TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating this.state.queryid.includes)`.

This error goes away when I set a number inside the `includes`parameter such as this: `this.state.queryid.includes(0)`.

What I tried to do in the backend is insert a `0` instead of `null` in the so that when I fetch it is understood to be `0` once uploaded. This did not work for react-native.

I just need help saying `If the item.id is null then set it as 0` or something like that. Also I am using the fetch api and flatlist:

```
    fetch(`https://www.example.com/React/user.php` , {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

   })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       this.setState({
         isLoading: false,
         dataSource: responseJson,
         user_image:  responseJson[0].user_images,
         },function() {


         });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       //console.error(error);
     });



<FlatList

       data={ this.state.user_image}




       renderItem={({item}) => <View>
       {this.state.queryid.includes(item.id)  ?
              <TouchableOpacity
               style={{alignSelf:'center', }}>
               <Animation
               progress={item.unprogress}
               source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}

               />
               </TouchableOpacity>
             :
             <TouchableOpacity
              style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
              <Animation
              progress={item.progress}
              source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}


              />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            }
       </View>
      />
```

Comment: The assertion is wrong: the `id` property in `this.state.queryid.includes(item.id)` does not necessarily evaluate to null when that error is thrown - there would be no error if it *could* be evaluated, even if it evaluated to null. Something *else* in that line is null - `queryid`?? - preventing evaluation of one of the properties.

Comment: @user2864740 yes I know, but I was wondering if I could probably ignore the `this.state.queryid.includes` code if there is no image uploaded. Because technically there is no json data (item.id) until something is upload therefore it's null

Comment: [`this.state.queryid.includes(item ? item.id : 0)`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/ternary-conditional-operator-in-typescript/)? (Assuming that it is `item` - and not `queryid` - that is null and that is truly the desired goal..)

Comment: Thank you I thought about what you said and when I checked to see if `queryid` was `null` and it was. But would it matter? Because the error goes away when I put a value in `includes`

Comment: @user2864740 Also the if statement is not working properly or I am probably not using it right.